# Is it okay if I use a species-specific tag for a closely related species?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday I asked this question: [What is the basic care needed for a siren?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5584/481)

Sirens are an aquatic salamander very closely related to axolotls, which we do have a tag for ([axolotl](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axolotl)). I don't want to create a tag for sirens, because I don't believe we'll get that many questions on them for a while, and I feel like there's going to be an overlap with axolotls.

If sirens require the same care as axolotls, and are closely related, should I use the [axolotls](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axolotls) tag for the question?

Answer (score 5):

Would it be reasonable (I know nothing of sirens or axolotls) to group both species under [aquatic-salamanders](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquatic-salamanders)?

Comment: Crazy timing, I just made the salamanders tag. So should we then put axolotl as a synonym for aquatic-salamanders I assume?

Comment: I don't even know if we need to be as specific as to prefix with "aquatic" at this time.

Comment: salamanders seems reasonable as a tag to me, but (again) I'm not familiar with them

Comment: Most salamanders are terrestrial, which is why I was thinking there should be some sort of separate tag for them. They'd have different questions.

Comment: I think a bigger thing with tags is sorting questions, rather than question content, if you get me.

Comment: How about a tag for each phylum? Genus/species seems too specific.

Comment: @zero298 I can't think of many pets that wouldn't be classified as chordates.

Comment: @MattS. you could have a starfish in a fishtank maybe?

Comment: @Zaralynda Yeah, invertebrates and mollusks would be different. I was just thinking of all the majority of questions we have being under the same tag. Which is why we have the top-level tags for dogs, cats, birds, reptiles, amphibians, and fish, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing wrong with many tags. At GL I encourage the usage of near-synonym tags. of course, call a synonym when you see one (like salamander, salamanders. Or lawn, lawns.) This is helpful to new users while putting up tags, who know their amphibian as an axolotls, rather than an 'aquatic salamander'. That way they can start typing 'ax-' and the computer will finish for them. :) Also, that way curious people can search the 'aquatic-salamanders' tag, or the 'axolotls' tag. Also, if this site grows a lot, which it has the potential to, each tag is liable to get a bit of use.